# PHP method_exists not working on class children?

Tags: php

```
class parent{
   function run($methodname) {
      echo method_exists(__CLASS__, $methodname);      
   }
}

class child extends parent {
   function order(){
      echo 'hello';
   }
}

$test = new child();
$test->run('order'); //false
```

The method_exists cannot find the method order in child class.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 10):

`__CLASS__` is bound to the class it's used in, not to inheriting classes. You can solve this by using `$this` as the object reference.

Also see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
echo method_exists($this, $methodname);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Reflection Class to get class details. Hope it helps

```
function ownMethodExist($class, $method)
{    
    $className = get_class($class);
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
    if($reflection->getMethod($method)->class == $className) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```